Getting object name limited to values defined in Set in TypeScript
I have some Set, which defines some IDs:
export const IDS: Set<number> = new Set<number>([1, 30, 50, 9999]);
Now I'd like to define mapping for their ID-SHA pairs in object structure:
export const IdMap: MapType= {
  1: '33b87373-cd6c-4c5b-873a-3290f0854a0b',
  30: '027c92d7-aab6-4047-82cd-fd5547100505',
  50: '3a9b2155-ecfe-4cde-9b9b-0f5c19876705',
  9999: 'cc498b4b-64e4-4215-bd55-6c3ce7367922',
};

The goal is to define MapType to enforce field names to be only from Set defined above. I've already tried several exotic constructs like:
type MapType= { [key in keyof typeof IDS]: string };
that looks reasonable, but don't work at all.
I'd be glad for any further assist

How about a Map? It’s already typically a better idea in JavaScript, but even more so in TypeScript with its structural typing. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAkgEQMoH0kBUCC64GEYC8MA2gIwA0MAzAAyUCsdMAnK8wLowCGEMokUANwAoAKYAPAA4gATrH7R4yQjDCiA7jCSioAHjABXALYAjUTIB8ACkSoM2PAEoRYqbPnhFcACYBZLpIAXDD+krpQAJ6SoiAAZkp2WDi4xIam5uyU0DIAlmAA5hYqapqhVsTCMCQUMADkVFQmABwA7FRtALTA3gBswB0ALMD0Jh2tVFwdVABMzDSxNE30A1w0JrWZlSS0lLU00y3AzNPeLR1cXCY9gzQDZ03T3R2x3vTLLaQ0NIz0G+RbxEYuwmzBM01Ibw6omAsVEg26cNBoI683owFIzFaPRa3z+ALYzF2wGAA0xJgGox6A1EA0G4PoHRMrwZfSowFEbWxx2mePYziAA

you can define your map as const, so it's keys and values will be statically known and can also use satisfies to ensure compatibility with certain type. Then you can refer to it's keys with `keyof typeof
example:
export const IdMap = {
  1: '33b87373-cd6c-4c5b-873a-3290f0854a0b',
  30: '027c92d7-aab6-4047-82cd-fd5547100505',
  50: '3a9b2155-ecfe-4cde-9b9b-0f5c19876705',
  9999: 'cc498b4b-64e4-4215-bd55-6c3ce7367922',
} as const satisfies Record<number, string>;

const someOtherObjectWithSameKeys: Record<keyof typeof IdMap, string> = {
  1: 'value',
  30: 'value',
  50: 'value',
  9999: 'value',
}

playground

Edit: you can also use Object.freeze to ensure the object won't be modified in runtime
export const IdMap = Object.freeze({
  1: '33b87373-cd6c-4c5b-873a-3290f0854a0b',
  30: '027c92d7-aab6-4047-82cd-fd5547100505',
  50: '3a9b2155-ecfe-4cde-9b9b-0f5c19876705',
  9999: 'cc498b4b-64e4-4215-bd55-6c3ce7367922',
}) satisfies Record<number, string>;


I would suggest a small amendment that keeps the IDs in a Set and ensures the map key numbers only come from that set https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkBmBlCwA8MB8UC8sUEAHsBAHYAmAzlGpgJblIQBOUASrgPydQBcUchABubAFDiAxgHty1YFACSAEVoFhAdzroAFAG0AjABooAZgAMpgKxWoATkf2AulACGtWfOABKANySJGAyrIpeCsqUALJuYPhQAN7iUFCGggDkZmYARgAcAOxmhQC0UpQAbFLFACxS1tnFBWZuxWYATPYWSBa51tVuFtnpxsnmFhkWbflS9m2U+cVubtnlNRbVC7ltZcVIlNZ9+YYWFrbWw6O2Gc322W2GB8UQUiw1ZRDFt7fFXdZShvYCuV8qcLiknPYMlIpNVAdlqg1ytUINUavdrMVsvsMZUzFIIIVgbM2hcAL7uTxyCLUNzABjUJAMCC0DjPEKULDwZD0DCgSAyJDKNTYUwKVhMADm2D8QA

@JaredSmith it's a valid suggestion, but I don't see benefits from it, as if you have to refactor the IDs, you'll have to change them twice. And defining separate array would consume more memory in runtime

@JaredSmith otherwise you'd better go for type IDs = 1 | 30 | 50 | 9999; ... Record<IDs, value>

What if the ids get used in more than just that map? What if there's a team upstream of the OPs that responsible for generating them and OP doesn't own them? I wrote that exact pattern in my playground link in the code base at work, and basically for those reasons. Really just depends on what the OP actually needs.
